# Where is the index.* file that is served as the MAMP start page URL?

Tags: apache, url, webserver, mamp

I'm trying to understand how MAMP manages the Apache web server but I cannot find the `index.*` file that is being served as the MAMP start page.

The virtual hosts configuration, `httpd-vhosts.conf`, is not included and `Applications/MAMP/htdocs` contains only my own site so how/where is `http://localhost/MAMP/?language=English` configured? The preferences for my installation of MAMP show that the 'Start page URL' is `/MAMP/`, is that an alias for another directory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `MAMP/htdocs` like you might expect, you will find all the "start page" stuff in `MAMP/bin/mamp` (e.g. the English language page is `MAMP/bin/mamp/English/index.php`).

This is due to the following line in `MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf`:

```
    Alias /MAMP "/Applications/MAMP/bin/mamp"
```

---

***A Word of Caution***

If you are using MAMP as a quick-and-easy web server (as many blogs recommend, since Apple annoyingly eliminated "Web Sharing" from the System Preferences), then these maintenance pages are available to everyone everywhere (thanks to the `Allow from all` you'll see in the config file near the alias).  **Everyone in the world can see your full php configuration and edit your database.**  The following aliases are also problematic.

```
    Alias /phpMyAdmin "/Applications/MAMP/bin/phpMyAdmin"
    Alias /SQLiteManager "/Applications/MAMP/bin/SQLiteManager"
```

You could try to lock down MAMP, but it's probably easier to just not use MAMP, since it is not intended to be used for live websites.  As the MAMP website itself says:

> MAMP was created primarily as a PHP development environment for Macintosh computer and should therefore not be used as Live Webserver for the Internet. In this case, we recommend that you use Mac OS X server with the provided Apache or a Linux server.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Goto Applications from finder
open up the MAMP folder
then open up htdocs