# After changing filename from index.html to index.php my project is no longer served with MAMP

Tags: php, server, mamp, local

I'm trying to do some PHP learnin' but I've run into a road-block. I have MAMP installed and I am successfully serving my project files locally. However, after renaming my index.html file to index.php, the page is no longer served.

url is: localhost/projectfile/

I can rename the file back to index.html and the page will serve up again but this means my php code won't run.

I've tried digging around MAMP to see if there is some information/ setting that could help but I'm not finding a solution. It would be great if anyone has info on how this could be solved. Thanks!

Comment: Did your MAMP started Apache server for serving PHP files ?

Comment: Hi @zire, yes apache is successfully running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone viewing this post- I must have edited a config file in the wrong way. I uninstalled MAMP and reinstalled and everything seems to be working properly now.

Answer (score 1):

You will find all the "start page" stuff in MAMP/bin/mamp (e.g. the English language page is MAMP/bin/mamp/English/index.php).

This is due to the following line in MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf:

```
Alias /MAMP "/Applications/MAMP/bin/mamp"
```

Refer [Where is the index.* file that is served as the MAMP start page URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20037400/3182574)